# KOTLIN/JAVA Remove some properties of an object from List of object

Tags: java, java-8, kotlin

I want to keep only a few properties of an object.
Lets say I have List of objects, `List<Employee>` and Employee data class has some 10 properties.
From the List, I would want to keep only 3-4 properties and filter out rest.
How can that be achieved in Java or Kotlin?
TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create separate data classes for your separate use cases:

```
data class Employee(val id: Long, val name: String, val age: Int, val position: String)
data class PartialEmployee(val id: Long, val name: String)
```

Then you can [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) between these as necessary:

```
val employees: List<Employee> = ...
val partialEmployees: List<PartialEmployee> = employees.map {
    PartialEmployee(
            id = it.id,
            name = it.name
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make `Employee` extends another class, put the properties that you want to keep in the superclass. Instead of `List<Employee>`, create a List of that superclass. For example:

```
calss A
{
    int propToKeep;
}

class B extends A
{
    @Override
    int propToKeep;

    int propToDrop;   
}
```

Then you can create a `List<A>` out of a bunch of `B`

Comment: That's neither Kotlin, nor is it a good solution (from an architecture point of view)